# mysql get month from timestamp not working

Tags: mysql, timestamp

I have a query that pulls the correct data form a db, but it does not return me the month from the timestamp. In the timestamp column I get a null value, even though the timestamp exsists.
It is stores in the DB as a bigInt (this wasnt my idea).

What I need is a date returned like this:

```
Course |  fcpd   |   Month
216    0.5         04
```

but I get:

```
Course |  fcpd   |   Month
216    0.5        null

SELECT mdl_quiz.course, mdl_quiz.fcpd, MONTH(mdl_quiz_grades.timemodified) as Month FROM mdl_quiz INNER JOIN mdl_quiz_grades ON mdl_quiz.course = mdl_quiz_grades.quiz WHERE mdl_quiz_grades.userid = 9428 AND mdl_quiz.course = 215
```

Could anyone point out where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to convert the timestamp back to a date first, before you can apply the `MONTH()` function.

```
MONTH(mdl_quiz_grades.timemodified)
```

becomes

```
MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(mdl_quiz_grades.timemodified))
```

Read more about it [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime).

And as a sidenote, `int` is enough for a timestamp, `bigint` is not necessary. A timestamp is a 32bit number, that's why it can hold the maximum date of January 19, 2038.

Comment: I'm having trouble with this because MONTH() function seems to return the month in GMT. In a different timezone the month and year can change a few hours earlier or later. For example, 1483228799 is December 31, 2016 in GMT, while it is already January 1, 2017 in India(GMT+5:30). Because of this, I'm unable to get accurate results for a query which is doing GROUP BY on MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp)).

Comment: @fancyPants Do you have any suggestion to solve this problem? I'm trying to get monthly count of entries in a table.

Comment: @rineez The datatype in the question here is an integer (which happens to be a timestamp). Store your data as the actual datatype timestamp. This considers timezones and stores internally as integer but displays as "datetime". Then you don't need the from_unixtime() function and can directly use the month() function.

Comment: @fancyPants FROM_UNIXTIME is not at all a problem for me. It is MONTH function that seems to be hard coded for GMT causing problem for me. Please completely read my comment above.

Comment: @rineez Yeah, I suggest you completely read my comment above, too. The solution is the datatype!

Comment: Sorry, No, data type did not solve it for me. Looks like MONTH function is actually responding to timezone change. The problem was default timezone for my connection was still set to GMT. I had to disconnect and reconnect mysql console to have the changes effected.

Answer (score -1):

```
"SELECT count(*) as records FROM sms WHERE MONTH(tarih)=MONTH(NOW()) and ceptel='"&ceptel&"'"
```

Comment: could you please improve the answer by writing about one sentence to explain why this works?