# How can i compare month with timestamp field in mysql query?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I want to get records of a month , like 8th month i.e august so how can i compare 8 with timestamp field

```
SELECT * FROM `reserve_Product` WHERE MONTH(`date`) = 8
```

Comment: What do you mean by compare?

Comment: possible duplicate of [mysql get month from timestamp not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16085629/mysql-get-month-from-timestamp-not-working)

Comment: i want to get records of a month , like 8th month i.e august so how can i compare 8 with timestamp field

Comment: MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(a_better_column_name))

Comment: select * from reserve_product where (month=(date("mm")=8))

Answer (score 1):

You have to use DATE_FORMAT

```
SELECT * FROM reserve_Product WHERE DATE_FORMAT(`date`, '%m') = 8
```

Try this fiddle : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ef36c/3

Answer (score 0):

even your query is correct but it will not use index due to month function and will be slow if table is bulky...so if you want performance also and just need aug'15 data then you can use below query-

```
SELECT * FROM 
reserve_Product 
WHERE `date` >= '2015-08-01 00:00:00' and `date` <= '2015-08-31 23:59:59';
```

But if you want august data for all years then you have to use date function.