# Mysql 8.0.22 month() function and group by

Tags: mysql, database, types, migration

I can't seem to figure out an underlying datatype issue (at least I think it is a datatype issue). Obviously writing here as I can't seem to put my finger on what is going wrong

Some background:
We have been trying to upgrade from mysql 5.7 to mysql 8.0.22 and I am tasked in checking database issues regarding inconsistencies. We fixed a timestamp datatype issue earlier in making sure both the times were in the same timezones and that seems to be in check. However, on mysql 8.0.22 I am facing a weird issue when grouping on this timestamp. Here is a small sample of the output that is eluding me:

[image]

The query essentially goes like

```
select year(date)
, month(date) 
, *aggregation(a)*
, *aggregation(b)*
etc. 
from blabla 
join blabla 
group by 1,2
```

It is just not making the month unique. I have a work around by using dateformat function however, I am just curious what might be causing this issue.  This same query is working fine on my 5.7 db. I have checked that both databases are exact replicas in multiple ways. Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

*edit* As people wanted exact context as to what is going on. Here is a simplified query from the same table that shows the problem at hand.
[image]

*edit no 2* I am adding the information schema and 10 rows for visibility of what the data looks like.

sample data:
[image]

schema:
[image]

Let me know if there is anything else you need to help me solve this. Apologies for the incomplete information. This part of database management/engineering or technical know how eludes me.

show create table results :

```
CREATE TABLE `order_status_history` (
   `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `order_id` int NOT NULL,
   `admin_user_id` int NOT NULL,
   `admin_user_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
   `order_status` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
   `date_update` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
   `o_type` enum('R','C','D') DEFAULT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
   KEY `indx_order_id` (`order_id`),
   KEY `indx_order_status` (`order_status`),
   KEY `indx_o_type` (`o_type`)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2375978 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Comment: Are you *actually* using `GROUP BY 1, 2` at the end of your query? Or are you saying `GROUP BY Year, month`?

Comment: This is impossible. Please provide complete query text, not a pattern.

Comment: Couldn't reproduce.

Comment: @matigo. I usually use group by 1,,2 etc. in all my queries and have never face any issues. Essentially should not make a difference as I am asking it to group by the first column. Issue is the same in both circumstances.

Comment: You know, it is highly encouraged that you post codes in textual form instead of photos. Simple reason is that if anyone want to test your query, wouldn't it be easier for them to copy textual codes than re-writing whatever on the photo?

Comment: This is not reproducible given the information provided. Please add table definitions as text to the question together with sample data.

Comment: You added some sample data and table definition but the table definition does not map to the columns in the sample data. Please add the result of show create table order_status_history and do include the sample in the same column order as the table column order..

Comment: @P.salmon added

Comment: Nothing obvious there I suggest you look a bit closer at low volume data in the raw.

Comment: Can you add `min(date_update)` and `max(date_update)` to your query, maybe there is something in common with those duplicate rows. How did the upgrade happen? Did you import a dump, or did you copy the data directory? In the latter case, try to import a dump (I assume it is not the live server) and/or test with a newly created copy of that table (e.g. create a new table and add all data into it). There has been some changes to timestamps in MySQL 8, maybe those introduced a bug. Does it happen too when you add an index? Can you test it with a version < 8.0.19 and/or <8.0.22?

Answer (score 0):

According to [the MySQL 8.0 docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_month), the `GETMONTH()` function works with a `date`, not a `timestamp`. So you would need to do something like `GETMONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(date_update))` for your query to return expected results. What's interesting is that you said this was working in MySQL 5.7, but [the docs for that function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_month) are identical to that found for 8.0. The one difference that your two installations *might* have is with the `lc_time_names` system variable, but this is just speculation.

[A similar question was asked on this site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16085629/mysql-get-month-from-timestamp-not-working) about eight years ago, and the accepted answer is the same as I outlined above.

Comment: Your linked question used an integer datatype for the "timestamp" (e.g. a number of seconds), not a timestamp datatype, and that caused the problem (to return `null`). For MySQL, a timestamp works the same way as a datetime (and can be used everywhere a datetime is used), but has a special behaviour regarding timezones. The big issue in the question here is that `group  by month` leads to non-unique results. Even if `month` would return incorrect (or no) values for timestamp, they should not lead to three rows with month = 9 when using `group by month`.